# How to get /dev/ttyUSB0 on my Pi Zero

Tags: usb, pi-zero

I am trying to use a CAN/USB adapter on my RPi Zero and read data through the USB port.

I have been following this tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/Read-and-write-from-serial-port-with-Raspberry-Pi/

But I can't find /dev/ttyUSB0!

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The link you are referring to is about a USB to serial adapter, not a CAN/USB adapter. A lot of USB/CAN adapters are not supported under Linux or need vendor specific drivers.

Comment: I am aware that the tutorial is about USB/Serial. But the tutorial uses ttyUSB0 to read data through USB, which is what I am interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved,

I just had to unplug it and plug it again, then my RPi noticed the device and the ttyUSB0 interface showed up.

OBS:
I opened up my USB/CAN adapter to see what was inside and i found out that there was a microcontroller converting the CAN to UART and a FTDI 1311 converting UART to USB. 
I guess thats why i am able to use the ttyUSB0 with my adapter.